# Does p-value have to be the same as the significance f

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-regression, p-value

I recently have conducted a multiple linear regression, and the significance F value is greater than 0.05 (not statically significant), however when calculating the p value it is less than 0.05 (statistically significant)

Does this contradict each other?

Comment: The F value is used to calculate the P value - whether or not the F value is significant or not depends on the degrees of freedom. Whether or not it is above or below 0.05 does not directly indicate significance.

Comment: thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The F statistic must be used in combination with the $p$ value when you are deciding if your overall results are significant.

If you have a significant result, it doesn't mean that all your variables are significant. The statistic is just comparing the **joint effect** of all the variables together.

If you relax some variables and do F statistics test again you may get better results.

If you are using the F Statistic in regression analysis (perhaps for a change in $R^2$, the Coefficient of Determination), you would use the $p$ value to decide.

If the $p$ value is bigger than the alpha level, your results are not significant and you cannot reject the null hypothesis, else you can.

A common alpha level for tests is 0.05, but for some purposes this may change.